# Como faço para percorrer um array e encontrar ids iguais?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Estou criando um jogo da memória, e quando clicado nas cartas, preciso que ele compare as duas e me retorne se são iguais ou não. Parece bobo, mas não sei como fazer isso. Sei que o código também não está dos melhores, mas quem puder dar uma força, eu agradeço.

````
  <v-container fluid class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-space-around mb-6">
    <v-sheet
      v-for="(carta, index) in cartasAleatorias"
      :key="index"
      width="100px"
      height="100px"
      rounded
      class="ml-4 mb-4"
      @click="virarCarta(carta)"
    >
      <v-img v-show="carta.virar" :src="carta.imgFrente"></v-img>
      <v-img v-show="!carta.virar" :src="carta.imgCostas"></v-img>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "TelaJogo",

  data: () => ({
    cartasAleatorias: [],
    cartas: [
      {
        id: 1,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img1.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img2.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img3.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img4.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img5.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img6.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img1.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img2.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img3.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img4.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img5.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        imgFrente: require("../../public/cartas/img6.png"),
        imgCostas: require("../../public/cartas/urso.png"),
        virar: false,
        parEncontrado: false,
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    virarCarta(carta) {
      carta.virar = !carta.virar;
    },
    aleatorias(cartas) {
      // Loop em todos os elementos
      for (let i = cartas.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // Escolhendo elemento aleatório
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        // Reposicionando elemento
        [cartas[i], cartas[j]] = [cartas[j], cartas[i]];
      }
      // Retornando array com aleatoriedade
      this.cartasAleatorias = cartas;
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    const cartas = this.cartas;
    this.aleatorias(cartas);
  },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: fala Laís.. acho que o filter foi bem respondido lá pelo @lucas-santos aqui tem a doc desse método [https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter](Array.prototype.filter()) 

agora quanto ao código, vou deixar só umas dicas pra vc pensar em clean code que pode te ajudar.. primeira coisa seria deixar todas variáveis/métodos em uma linguagem só (pt ou en).
os requires normalmente vem antes dos códigos em qlqr linguagem.. isto iria reduzir tb os requires duplicados para urso.png

Comment: métodos normalmente são verbos, então `aleatorias` talvez seria `tornarAleatoria`.
atributos normalmente são adjetivos, então `virar: false`, talvez se encaixe melhor como `virado: false`
acho que não existe isso de código ruim.. só código que custou menos tempo pra nós, seja de estudo ou de dedicação msm..
espero poder contribuir ;)

Answer (score -3):

Fiz um exemplo usando JavaScript puro, no caso apenas a lógica básica focada no array, dê uma olhada como fiz e veja se tem como adaptar para o seu contexto ai usando Vue (acho que é Vue)

O que fiz foi o seguinte:

```js
const cartas = [
    { id: 123, nome: 'carta 1' },
    { id: 123, nome: 'carta 2' },
    { id: 321, nome: 'carta 3' },
    { id: 321, nome: 'carta 4' },
];

function compararCarta(cartaClicada) {
    const cartasIguais = cartas.filter(carta => (
        carta.id === cartaClicada.id
    ));

    return cartasIguais;
}

const cartasIguais = compararCarta(cartas[1]);
console.log(cartasIguais);
```